# What is the concat doing?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the '09' doing in this code?

```
select CONCAT(TRIM((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'mm/dd/yyyy')))),(TRIM((TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate), '09')))))
from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'09'` is part of the `to_char()` call, not the `concat()`. It is [a format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C) being applied to the extracted month number when it is converted to a string. Without that you would get a plain `5`:

```
select TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate))
from dual;

TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTHFROMSYSDATE))      
----------------------------------------
5
```

Specifying that format mask means you get a leading zero for month numbers below ten.

```
select TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate), '09')
from dual;

TO_
---
 05
```

You're then trimming the leading space off, but you can avoid that by adding FM to that mask:

```
select TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate), 'FM09')
from dual;

TO_
---
05
```

Other areas are odd too; the conversion of `sysdate` to a string and back to a date seems pointless, and you have a lot of parentheses you don't need, and a redundant trim. You can simplify to:

```
select CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate), TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate), 'FM09'))
from dual;

CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE),TO_CHAR(EXT
-------------------------------------------
201905
```

or with the concatenation operator:

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate), 'FM09')
from dual;

EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE)||TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(M
-------------------------------------------
201905
```

or don't treat the year and month as separate numeric elements at all:

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')
from dual;

TO_CHA
------
201905
```

Answer (score 1):

The `09` is a format Definition in the `TO_CHAR` function for formatting Numbers. A leading Zero is added to a single digit number.

Example: `7` will be returned as `07`

See [Oracle Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) for more detailed information on the different formats

Comment: Liked this one better, simple and it provides a link to the documentation.